# What are the standard stability derivative formulas and typical GA values?

Tags: aerodynamics

What are the standard [stability derivative formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_derivatives) and typical GA values?

I suppose values for the C172 would be the best benchmark.

Comment: try [this web page](http://www.megginson.com/Aviation/roskam-coefficients.html). However, it only lists the C182 and C310 besides other non-GA airplanes.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have it in front of me, but this book has the pertinent derivatives to consider, along with C172-ish values.

*Aerodynamics, Aeronautics, and Flight Mechanics*, 2nd Edition
Barnes W. McCormick
ISBN: 978-0-471-57506-1 September 1994 672 Pages